# How do I add multiple values from checkboxes into a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a form which contains two sets of checkboxes and would like to store them in a MySQL Database however when I post to the Database all the data comes through as intended such as the date, text and radio buttons except for the two textboxes. If I look into the database the columns where the value for the textboxes is stored it only says "Array" and none of the actual values.

This is my code that handles the post request:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$name = $_POST['input4'];
$datedone = $_POST['date'];
$projectnumber = $_POST['input1'];
$area   = $_POST['input2'];
$donebefore = $_POST['radio9'];
$changesmade    = $_POST['radio8'];
$safeaccess = $_POST['radio11'];
$electrical = $_POST['radio5'];
$machineguarding    = $_POST['radio6'];
$correctequipment   = $_POST['radio4'];
$sds    = $_POST['radio3'];
$controltoxic   = $_POST['radio1'];
$ppe    = $_POST['radio2'];
$hazard = $_POST['checkbox'];
$otherhazards   = $_POST['input3'];
$controlofhazards   = $_POST['checkbox1'];
$monitor    = $_POST['radio12'];
$comments   = $_POST['input'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO hira (Name, TodayDate, ProjectNumber, Area, DoneBefore, HaveChangesMade, SafeAccess, ElectricalEquipment, MachineGuarding, CorrectEquipment, SDS, ControlToxic, PPE, Hazard, OtherHazard, ControlHazard, MonitorProcess, AdditionalComments) VALUES ('$name','$datedone','$projectnumber','$area','$donebefore','$changesmade','$safeaccess','$electrical','$machineguarding','$correctequipment','$sds','$controltoxic','$ppe','$hazard','$otherhazards','$controlofhazards','$monitor','$comments')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Thank you for completing the Hira form";

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

What have I done wrong here. I would like the values of the textboxes stored comma separated i.e. "Noise, Dust"
Is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: print_r $_POST you will get it, what went wrong, trust me

Answer (score 0):

you can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function

```
$checkbox = implode(",",$_POST['checkbox']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function for insert array using , seperated string

```
$values = implode(",",$_POST['name']);
```

you can use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to retrieve the string to array

```
$values = explode(",",$values);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, however when I use